# Rotations, harmonic oscillators, Gaussians, ladders

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry

I am trying to understand better the quantization of the harmonic oscillator.

---

Here are three ways of thinking about the harmonic oscillator.

- Eigenfunctions of the differential operator: $H = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + x^2$
- Eigenfunctions of the oscillator $H = a a^\dagger+ \frac{1}{2}$
- Special orbits of the $U(1)$ action on the complex plane, level sets of the moment map $H = p^2 + x^2$.

Are there any places that explain all three of these on equal footing?  Items 1 and 2 have a [Wick formula](https://web.archive.org/web/20160803213226/http://www.lptl.jussieu.fr/files/fi.pdf)
$$ \langle a b c d\rangle = \langle a b \rangle \langle c d\rangle + \langle a c \rangle \langle b d\rangle + \langle a d \rangle \langle bc \rangle$$
Is there an analogue in the symplectic geometry case (item 3)?

I want to understand better why this is a duality

$$ {\tt rotation,}\;e^{it}\in U(1)\leftrightarrow {\tt gaussians,}\;e^{-x^2} \leftrightarrow {\tt eigenstates, }\;|n\rangle$$

Something to that effect, mentioned in these [notes](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/notes23.pdf).  Does any rotation action get quantized this way?

---

This question involves rotation actions, in a different way than this other MO qustion:
[Characterizing the harmonic oscillator creation and annihilation operators in a rotationally invariant way](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35054/characterizing-the-harmonic-oscillator-creation-and-annihilation-operators-in-a-r)

**EDIT** Here is another MO post where the Bargmann transform arises in quantization of the harmonic oscillator:
[Representation of double cover of $U(n)$ on eigenspaces of harmonic oscillator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94535/representation-of-double-cover-of-un-on-eigenspaces-of-harmonic-oscillator)

Answer (score 5):

The first two representations are related by the [Bargmann transform](https://planetmath.org/bargmanntransform), which is a unitary transformation between $L^2( \mathbb{R}, dx)$ and $L^2( \mathbb{C}, e^{-z\bar{z}}dzd\bar{z})$. This transformation expresses the invariance of the quantization under the change of polariztion: real in the first case and Kähler in the second case. (Both cases treat the quantization of $\mathbb{C} = T^{*}\mathbb{R}$ with their canonical symplectic forms).

The third case coresponds to the quantization of $\mathbb{C^{\times}}$ in real polarization, which corresponds basically to performing the canonical transformation:

$ dx\wedge dp =  dH\wedge d\theta $

before quantization. It is a result by [Śniatycki](https://books.google.com/books?id=r-vTMQEACAAJ), that upon choosing a real polarization along the radius, the quantization space is spanned by "distributional wave functions" having support only on the Bohr-Sommerfeld fibers which are the level sets corresponding to the quantized Harmonic oscillator energies. There are two recent Arxiv articles by Śniatycki ([first](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1302), [second](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1477)), where he reviews his Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization and treats further applications.